# Is it possible to add button to scratchpad?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to develop Firefox add-on which should add new elements to the internal developer's tools such as `console` and `scratchpad`.

I'm trying to do this in most simple way possible — via firefox addons SDK (Jetpack), however in documentation mentions only about adding elements to main toolbar only.

Is it possible at all to add button on scratchpad toolbar? If yes, where I could find an code example?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just curious, what would this button do? We're working on providing Jetpack apis for the devtools, and use cases like this help us understand what people are interested in building.

Comment: @canuckistani Very simple: scratchpad is a great tool, but if page has several `iframe` tags it is impossible to attach scratchpad to the one of the nested frames. Yes, it is possible to use `cd()` command from the console. But this is not really usable and not that explicit. It is also impossible to put `cd()` statement inside scratchpad code, since `cd` will be executed every time scratchpad code is run, while it should be executed only once when page was loaded / reloaded.

Comment: @canuckistani Another idea is to give ability to attach libraries to the current context (since it's not a real world case, when you have only one JS file you're working with). I'm talking about more or less about creating http://jsfiddle.net/ clone inside FF.

Comment: For your first problem, we're working on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977043, and for your second problem we recently landed a developer toolbar command to do this: http://note.io/1qEcU2s I do think your jsfiddle features idea is very interesting! We will be landing new devtools sdk apis soon that will make all of this a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. I don't know about the SDK methods, but here it is non-sdk.

Use the following code:

```
var devtools = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {}).devtools;
var HUDService = devtools.require("devtools/webconsole/hudservice");

var hud = HUDService.getBrowserConsole();
if (!hud) {
  //browser console is not open
} else {

  var btnClear = hud.chromeWindow.document.querySelector('.webconsole-clear-console-button');
  var newBtn = hud.chromeWindow.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'toolbarbutton');
  var props = {
    class: 'devtools-toolbarbutton',
    label: 'blah',
  }
  for (var p in props) {
    newBtn.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
  }

  btnClear.parentNode.insertBefore(newBtn, btnClear.nextSibling);
}
```

This code inserts a button after the "clear" button.

Note the area where messages are logged, that's an iframe in html namespace, but the stuff around it is xul namespace. (im pretty sure)

Comment: `xul namespaces crap`?!

Comment: ok ok i fixed the code :P also now checks if hud is open or not first

Comment: i tested my code, no clue why but `hud.chromeWindow.document.insertBefore(newBtn, btnClear.nextSibling)` throws `Exceptions: Node not found` so I changed it to `btnClear.parentNode.insertBefore` and it works fine now.

Comment: For this to work with the SDK, all you'd need to to is add `const { Cu } = require('chrome');` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

> simple way possible — via firefox addons SDK (Jetpack)

That's actually more or less the "hardest way possible". The SDK makes things easy for stuff it supports out of the box, like adding toolbar button to the main window, or context menu items, etc. But when it comes to things the SDK is not tailored for, like is the case here, you'd actually have to write SDK boilerplate + low-level XUL/XPCOM stuff and cannot use XUL overlays as an added bonus (because restartless add-ons don't support those).

#### Scratchpad - with a XUL overlay

Here is a *complete* XUL overlay add-on.

`install.rdf`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>my@addon</em:id>
    <em:name>My Add-on</em:name>
    <em:version>1</em:version>
    <em:creator>Nils Maier</em:creator>

    <!-- Firefox -->
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>30.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>33.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

`chrome.manifest`

```
content my-addon ./
overlay chrome://browser/content/devtools/scratchpad.xul chrome://my-addon/content/overlay.xul
```

`overlay.xul`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <commandset id="sp-commandset">
    <command id="my-addon-button-command" oncommand="alert('hellow, world');"/>
  </commandset>
  <toolbar id="sp-toolbar">
    <toolbarbutton id="my-addon-button" command="my-addon-button-command"
      class="devtools-toolbarbutton" label="My Add-on button"/>
  </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

The point is: Modify [`scratchpad.xul`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/devtools/scratchpad/scratchpad.xul) as you like.

#### Scatchpad - Using the SDK

In the SDK, since you cannot use overlays, you'd have to:

1. Register an observer via [`nsIWindowWatcher.registerNotification`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowWatcher) (The SDK used to have something for this, but it has been deprecated)
2. Listen for windows with the proper `chrome://browser/content/devtools/scratchpad.xul` locations, disregarding other windows.
3. Once such a window is opened, listen for it to `load`.
4. Once `load`ed, use the DOM API to manually inject the DOM elements you want in there (replacing the overlay)
5. Make sure you handle things correctly when the window is unloaded again.
6. Make sure to clean up after yourself when your add-on is disabled (remove any UI from any still-open windows again and, of course, the observer itself).

#### Console

You didn't really specify which console, the Browser Console, or the per-page Console?

Anyway, you'd overlay, [`chrome://browser/content/devtools/webconsole.xul`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/devtools/webconsole/webconsole.xul)

In the SDK things get more tricky, because the per-page Web Console is not actually a top-level window:

- You'd need to watch for it being a top-level window (Browser Console)
- watch for `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` and handle `load` events for the console URI (loaded into `<xul:iframe>`).
- and the same for `chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox-window.xul` when the devtools are displayed in a detached window.